# Using redux-form with thunk middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I recently found out about `redux-form` and it seems pretty awesome.

I am trying to remotly submit a form. I created a separate button as `redux-form` docs said:

```
class RemoteSubmitButton extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log("RSB:", submit('newComment'));
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        return (
          // newComment is the name of the form
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => dispatch(submit('newComment'))}>Submit</button>
      )
    }
}

// NewComment is my form component that I created
NewComment = reduxForm({
    form: 'newComment',
    onSubmit: postComment
})(NewComment);
```

and postComment function looks like this:

```
export const postComment = (comment) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    console.log("postComment - comment:", comment);
    return api.postComment(comment).then(response => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS',
            response
        });
    });
}
```

What I get is absolutely nothing after submitting the form. The problem is the `postComment` function, and specifically `=> (dispatch, getState) =>` part. Without it I can see the logs, but I can't dispatch a `POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS`.

How can I make this work?

**EDIT**

```
class NewComment extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div class="new-comment">
                <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
                    <Field .../>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the NewComment component that has the form? You need to ensure that you are still passing the handleSubmit to the form's onSubmit like so <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>.

Comment: I am passing my postFunction to my NewComment component using through a container, that gets the `postComment` function using a `connect` method. Still with `onSubmit` mounted to the form I get no results at all.

Comment: If the inner function of `postComment` is never called, then it's likely that the redux-thunk middleware is not set up properly.

Comment: It must be, as if I try to call the action using a simple button with `this.props.postComment` passed to `onClick` it works. But it does not work when going through the form